# MySQL InnoDB - how to make tables append only?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Do you know how to configure MySQL Innodb tables to make it append only? That is only insertions are allowed, and updates or deletions are not? How to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: To protect someone from accidentally or purposely deleting or updating rows of some tables. That means only INSERT statements are allowed, and DELETE and UPDATE statements are not.

Comment: Read about mysql user privileges : [here](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO16962.html)

Comment: What I want is that for all users, including root that: 1, they can only INSERT; 2, they cannot DELETE or UPDATE. Are there any such things?

Comment: I already mentioned about "privileges in mysql". Please read about it instead of expecting anyone here to post exact query for you to copy and paste at your end. Thanks.

Comment: As sumit badaya already mentioned: use [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). If you want to forbid something, you actually have to allow everything else (so it's harder to maintain, because you have to write grants for all tables for all users). An easy solution is to put that table into a different database and make the grants there, then you can keep the simple (all inclusive) grants for your main database. You can set that permissions for root too, but root can of course change that again, because he is root.

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed...  `GRANTs` seem to be the way to do it.  But you have to *allow* everything else to everyone, including root.  That is impractical and unmaintainable.  Furthermore, you should not restrict `root`.

Add `TRIGGERs` "before UPDATE" and "before DELETE" to check for what is going on.  Then give an error in both cases.  This will catch even `root`, and does not involve any changes to the `GRANTs`.